# Integral involving directional derivative of solution to Laplace's equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

$u$ is a harmonic function, and we have
$$\Phi(x):=\begin{cases}-\frac{1}{2\pi}\log|x|&&(n=2)\\\\ \frac{1}{n(n-2)\alpha(n)}\frac{1}{|x|^{n-2}}&&(n\geq 3)\end{cases},$$
$$u(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Phi(x-y)f(y)\mathrm{d}y.$$

It is claimed, at the top of page 34, that
$$
\left|\int_{\partial B(x,\epsilon)}
                  \Phi(y-x) \frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}(y)
                  \mathrm{d}S(y)
\right| \leq C\epsilon^{n-1}\max\limits_{\partial B(0,\epsilon)}|\Phi|,$$

where $\nu$ is the outward normal from $\partial B(x,\epsilon)$ and $\alpha(n)$ is the volume of the $n$-dimensional unit ball.

How did Evans get this bound?

Comment: Is $\int_{\partial B(x,\epsilon)} (1)\,dS(y)$proportional to $\epsilon^{n-1}$?  And is the normal derivative of $u$  is continuous on $\partial B$?  If so, can you conclude now?  But it seems that the bound is "lousy" since $\Phi \sim \epsilon^{2-n}$ on the boundary.   So, the integral is $O(\epsilon)$.

Comment: Isn't $\int_{\partial B(x,\epsilon)}(1)\mathrm{d}S(y)$ just the surface area of the $n$-dimensional ball of radius $\epsilon$, i.e. $n\epsilon^{n-1}\alpha(n)$ (where $\alpha(n)$ is the volume of the $n$-dimensional unit ball)? Because then, yes, it is proportional to $\epsilon^{n-1}$.

Comment: Yes, it is.  So, this should give a big clue on a way to develop the estimate.

Comment: @Dr.MV Forgetting about the normal derivative for a second, $\left| \int_{\partial B(x,\epsilon)}\Phi(y-x)\mathrm{d}S(y)\right|\lesssim  \|\Phi\|_{\infty}\left| \int_{\partial B(x,\epsilon)}(1)\mathrm{d}S(y)\right| \lesssim \epsilon^{n-1} \|\Phi\|_{\infty}$.

Comment: And the normal derivative is bounded.  So ...

Comment: $u$ is in $\mathcal{C}^2(U)$, where $U$ contains the given ball. Is it from here that we can tell that $u$'s normal derivative is continuous on the boundary? And to tell that its integral is bounded, does that come from the fact that 'continuous' $\implies$ 'locally integrable'?

Comment: Yes.  Since $B(x,\epsilon)$ in contained in $R^n$, and $u$ is harmonic, then its partial derivatives are continuous and thus bounded.